How to Maximize $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{M_{k}}{m_{i} - \sum_{p=1}^{k} M_{p}}$
This is from a physics problem : A rocket with initial velocity $v_{i}$ and initial mass $m_{i}$ shoots $n$ pellets. The final mass and velocity of the rocket is $m_{f}$ and $v_{f}$. Determine the mass of each $k$th pellet such that the final velocity $v_{f}$ is maximized. (Of course, the mass of each pellet does not have to be the same, but the sum is constant since $m_{i}$ and $m_{f}$ are constants.)
This cannot be solved with the usual Tsiolkovsky Rocket Equation since it is a discrete situation.
After some math I showed that the following should be maximized,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{M_{k}}{m_{i} - \sum_{p=1}^{k} M_{p}} $$
where $M_{p}$ is the mass of each pellet. How do I maximize this? We know that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} M_{k} = m_{i} - m_{f} = const$.

What is $i$ in the formulae ?

@ClaudeLeibovici $m_{i}$ is just the initial mass which is constant.

You have used the assumption that each shoot has the same velocity of each $M_p$, right!

@MathArt Not the same velocity though - the same "relative velocity" to the rocket, so the velocity itself is different.

I don't know about the physics, but are you sure you want to find the maximum instead of the minimum? The maximum is easy:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{M_k}{m_i - \sum_{p=1}^k M_p}\le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{M_k}{m_i-(m_i-m_f)} = \frac{m_i-m_f}{m_f}$$
which is achieved when e.g. $M_1=m_i-m_f, M_2=M_3=\cdots=0$.
To find the minimum is not hard either.
Do the variable change $s_k:=m_i - \sum_{i=1}^k M_p$. In particular $m_i=s_0\ge s_1\ge\cdots \ge s_n=m_f$. So we want to optimize the function $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s_{k-1}-s_k}{s_k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s_{k-1}}{s_k}-n$$
It suffices to optimize $f=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s_{k-1}}{s_k}$ instead.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s_{k-1}}{s_k}\ge n (\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{s_{k-1}}{s_k})^{1/n}= n(\frac{m_i}{m_f})^{1/n}$$
due to the AM-GM inequality, and the equality is achieved iff $\frac{s_{k-1}}{s_k}$ is a constant $C$.
As $C^n=\frac{m_i}{m_f}$, we have $\frac{s_{k-1}}{s_k}=(\frac{m_i}{m_f})^{1/n}$
When $k=1$, we get $s_1=\frac{s_0}{(\frac{m_i}{m_f})^{\frac{1}{n}}}=m_f^{1/n}m_i^{1-1/n}$. Inductively $$s_k = m_f^{k/n}m_i^{1-k/n}$$
Also $$\min = n (\frac{m_i}{m_f})^{1/n} -n = \frac{(\frac{m_i}{m_f})^{1/n}-1}{1/n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln (\frac{m_i}{m_f})$$
the reminiscence of Tsiolkovsky rocket equation.
Remark: $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s_{k-1}-s_k}{s_k}$ is actually a Riemann sum of the integral $\int_{m_f}^{m_i}\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln(\frac{m_i}{m_f})$ and for each interval $[s_k, s_{k-1}]$, the sample point is taken on the left end, hence the Riemann sum is always bigger than the integral. This also shows that no matter how we divide the pellets, as long as $m_k=s_k-s_{k-1}$ is becoming infinitesimal (approaching $0$), the integral always converges to the Tsiolkovsky result. In terms of physics, no matter what the dynamical process of burning the fuel is (as long as the burning is continuous), the added velocity is always the same. So the above convergence as $n\rightarrow\infty$ has no significance (but as a minimal sum for a given number of division, it does converge faster than other routes).

It actually ended up in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

Oh it was actually the minimum, my bad.
